# Prove the ring equivalent of Cayley's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove the ring equivalent of Cayley's theorem using undergraduate introductory abstract algebra techniques.

I've seen this stated "Every ring $R$ is isomorphic to an endomorphic subring of some abelian group $A$".

My assumption would be to let $A = (R,+,0)$

in other words, the additive abelian group of ring $R$.

Then, we can say that $f: R \rightarrow End(A)$ where $f(r)$ is the left multiplication map (by $r$) $A \rightarrow A$

This is a particularly fundamental theorem that I've been very confused to not see a proof for online.

Comment: The answer to that post is outside of anything I've seen in undergraduate courses. For example, epimorphisms and monomorphisms have not been discussed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have found an easy "proof online" at this site. So it is indeed online.